# jQuery setInterval on slider advance button

Tags: jquery, slider, setinterval

I am trying to do a slider and having some problems about it.As you can see I have a #timer button, when you clicked the button, it advances the next slide, there is no problem with it.

But I want it to click itself so I am trying to use setInterval but can't do it. Also there is no problem about triggering first click on navitem, but can't setInterval on that button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.slideritem p').stop(true).show(1000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideritem').hide();
    $('.slideritem:first').fadeIn(1000);

    $('.navitem').click(function () {
        var index = $('.navitem').index(this)
        var indexlast = $('.navitem').index(this) + 1
        $('.slideritem').hide();
        $('.slideritem:nth-child(' + indexlast + ')').stop(true).fadeIn(1000);
        $('.navitem img ').removeClass('current');
        $('.navitem:nth-child(' + indexlast + ') img ').addClass('current');

        $('#timer').click(function () {
            index++$('.slideritem').hide();
            $('.slideritem').eq(index).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.navitem img').removeClass('current');
            $('.navitem img').eq(index).addClass('current');

            if (index == 3) {
                index = -1
            }
        });
    });

    $('.navitem:first').trigger('click');
    setInterval($('#timer').trigger('click'), 1500);
});    
</script>
```

Comment: @Tushar Gupta 
http://jsfiddle.net/YjEzD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trigger the click event for this. It's a bad habit.

Make a separate function for the sliding effect. Then call it from click, and from the timer separately.

Should be something like:

```
function Slide() {
    // Perform the sliding here
}

$('#timer').click(Slide);

setInterval(Slide,1500);
```

I did some improvements for your code and now it's working. There are several more things you can improve...

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YjEzD/1/)

Comment: Why is it a bad habit?

Comment: It is a slider but it has no slide effect, it has some fadeIn fadeOut effects.Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YjEzD/

Comment: @putvande I believe it's a bad habit because maybe the click event will someday do other actions except the sliding, but the Interval is still supposed to only slide. So creatine a separate function for the sliding is the best practice

Comment: @Itay, Thanks it works but what is the difference? What is the wrong thing i did? And also now i need to break Interval if it is clicked by hand.if(!slide) condition might work.What is your idea about this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To see the differences just compare your code to my code... I can't explain everything here. To reset the interval, read about stopping timers with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval), and then set the interval again.